# How does the compiler calls operator casting?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, casting

can somebody ewxplain me how the compiler calls the operator casting:

```
operator ELEMENT()const { 
return pArray->arr[index]; 
}
```

From line 6 in main:

```
(*ptr3)[0] = a1[0] + a2[1];
```

How adding two ELEMENT object with + operator even allowed? There is no + operator overloading in ELEMENT class.

Thanks,
Liron

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class ELEMENT> class Array 
{
    class Element 
    { 
        Array<ELEMENT>* pArray;
        int index; 
    public: 
        Element(Array<ELEMENT>* p, int i) 
            : pArray(p), index(i) {} 
        const Element& operator=(const ELEMENT& e) { 
            pArray->set(index, e); // call copy-on-write 
            return *this; 
        } 
        operator ELEMENT()const { 
            return pArray->arr[index]; 
        } 
    }; 
        friend class Element; 
    ELEMENT* arr; 
    int size; 
    int* ref_counter; 
    void attach(const Array& a) { 
        arr = a.arr; size = a.size; 
        ref_counter = a.ref_counter; 
        ++(*ref_counter); 
    } 
    void detach() { 
        if(--(*ref_counter) == 0) { 
            delete []arr; 
            delete ref_counter; 
        } 
    } 
    void set(int index, const ELEMENT& e) { 
        if(*ref_counter > 1) { // need copy-on-write! 
            Array temp = clone(); 
            detach(); 
            attach(temp); 
        } 
        arr[index] = e; 
    } 
public: 
    explicit Array(int);
    Array<ELEMENT> clone()const; 
    Array(const Array<ELEMENT>& a){attach(a);} 
    ~Array(){detach();} 
    const Array& operator=(const Array<ELEMENT>& a) { 
        detach(); attach(a); return *this; 
    } 
    Element operator[](int index) { 
        return Element(this, index); 
    } 
    const ELEMENT& operator[](int index)const { 
        return arr[index]; 
    } 
};
template<class ELEMENT> 
Array<ELEMENT>::Array(int size1) 
    : size(size1), ref_counter(new int(1)) 
{ 
    arr = new ELEMENT[size]; 
} 
template<class ELEMENT> 
Array<ELEMENT> Array<ELEMENT>::clone()const { 
    Array temp(size); 
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i) { 
        temp.arr[i] = arr[i]; 
    } 
    return temp; 
} 
int main() 
{
    Array<int> a1(1), a2(2); 
    Array<int>* ptr3 = new Array<int>(3); 
    a2[0] = 1; 
    a2[1] = 2; 
    a1 = a2; 
    (*ptr3)[0] = a1[0] + a2[1]; 
    (*ptr3)[1] = a1[1] + a2[0]; 
    cout << (*ptr3)[0] << ", " << (*ptr3)[1] << endl; 
    delete ptr3; 
    return 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How adding two ELEMENT object with + operator even allowed? There is no + operator overloading in ELEMENT class.

`ELEMENT` is not a class, it's a type parameter. And in your example the type given for that parameter is `int`. Obviously `int` does have a `+` operator, so that works fine. If you tried to create an `Array<SomeType>` where `SomeType` did not have a `+` operator, you would get an error.

There is an `Element` class and that class does indeed have no `+` operator, but that class is implicitly convertible to `ELEMENT` (i.e. `int` in this case), so when you apply `+` to objects of the `Element` the compiler adds a call to that conversion operator and `+` is applied to the result.